# Gerar nova migrations baseado em todos os models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Preciso criar uma migrations com todos os model criados (acabei apagando a primeira migration e não estou conseguindo criar o banco de dados de autenticação).

Comment: Se você tenta criar novamente usando o comando `Add-Migration NomeDaMigration` e mesmo assim ele não gerar, então se você puder (verifique antes se você não tem dados confidenciais que não podem ser perdidos por exemplo), uma opção é excluir o banco de dados e, em seguida, executar o comando `Update-Database`. Feito isso você tenta gerar novamente com o comando `Add-Migration NomeDaMigration`. **Caso isso resolva eu insiro como resposta** :-)

Comment: Não resolve. Ele continua a gerar uma nova migration, porém vazia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Caso apenas a migração tenha sido apagada(ainda com o ModelSnapshot e com a base ainda criada)**:

apague o arquivo ModelSnapshot e TODOS os qrquivos relacionados a migrações (*.Designer.cs e *.resx)(ficam na pasta Migrations) e rode o Add-Migration com o mesmo nome da migração anterior(para garantir que, no banco em que a migração já tenha sido rodada, o sistema não tente criar toda a estrutura novamente, caso tenha duvida em relação ao nome da migração, efetue um select na tabela "__EFMigrationsHistory" no banco onde esta migração já foi rodada e olhe seu nome, é útil você mudar o nome da classe da migração criada para que fique IDÊNTICO ao nome nesta tabela).

Comment: Não tem nenhum ModelSnapshot na pasta migrations.

Comment: E mesmo assim o Add-Migration continua gerando vazio?

Comment: se sim, poderia limpar executar um delete na tabela "__EFMigrationsHistory"(pode ser de todos os dados mesmo) e tentar novamente?

Comment: Já fiz esses procedimentos. Continua a gerar um migration vazio.

Comment: Você poderia abrir sua pasta "Migrations" no explorer e me dizer quais arquivos estão nela?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l1gozb

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83967/discussion-between-guilherme-barros-and-paulo).